# Error while getting list of column names from a Firebird database table

Tags: python, database, firebird, firebird2.5

I tried several times to get a list of tables in firebird using python I tried this [Get list of column names from a Firebird database table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19258749/get-list-of-column-names-from-a-firebird-database-table/33583567#33583567):

```sql
select rdb$field_name from rdb$relation_fields where rdb$relation_name=factura;
```

but didn't work it shows the error `('Error while preparing SQL statement:\n- SQLCODE: -206\n- Dynamic SQL Error\n- SQL error code = -206\n- Column unknown\n- FACTURA\n- At line 1, column 72', -206, 335544569)`

Also tried using `show table factura;` but the I recibe the error `('Error while preparing SQL statement:\n- SQLCODE: -104\n- Dynamic SQL Error\n- SQL error code = -104\n- Token unknown - line 1, column 1\n- show', -104, 335544569)`

So, I dont know how to get this list of tables.

Comment: I have included the query you posted as an 'answer' to the linked question, as it makes a lot more clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: I have included the query into your answer as it makes it easier to answer.

You get the *column unknown - FACTURA* error because your where-clause is:

```sql
where rdb$relation_name=factura
```

Your unquoted use of `factura` makes it a column name of `rdb$relation_fields`, but no such column exists. This causes the error.

Instead you want to select rows whose `rdb$relation_name` column have the (string) value `factura`, that means you need to enclose it in single quotes (as was also shown in [the accepted answer of the question you refer to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19258750/466862)):

```sql
where rdb$relation_name='factura'
```

or, given case (in)sensitivity rules of column names:

```sql
where rdb$relation_name='FACTURA'
```

The reason `show table factura` doesn't work, is because that isn't part of the SQL syntax of Firebird, it only exists in the Firebird ISQL tool.

Answer (score 0):

That only works if factura is the name of the table

Answer (score 0):

Also the table name must be uppercase, or no names will be found. Try:

```
select rdb$field_name
from   rdb$relation_fields
where  rdb$relation_name='FACTURA'
order by rdb$field_position;
```

The *order by* is optional. The **single quotes** and **upper case table name** are not.